# find: Why is the -a operator not commutative in combination with -print?

Tags: find

Supposing we're using find in current directory with audio files (e. g. MP3) and (important!) also non-mp3 files (e. g. JPEG) present in current directory or somewhere below it.
Additionally to that, we have a directory in there with some other audio files 
(called **exclude_me** in the example), which should live up to its name by being excluded from the file search:

```
find . \( -type d -name 'exclude_me' -prune \) -o \( -type f -a -iname '*.mp3' -a -print \)
```

*(Though not absolutely necessary in this case, I've deliberately set some redundant parentheses, as well as additional `-a` operators for the sake of clarity.)*

Because of the explicit `-print` option (cf. also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), this will indeed omit anything from "exclude_me" directory, and only list the *.mp3 files recursively from current directory.
Sometimes (not always) the `alias` command  may already be sufficient for a `find` one-liner, but this command will require the argument at the **end** of the line.
Taking notice that the '*.mp3' argument to -iname is *before* the `-print` in this case, there appears to be no way to solve the problem with an `alias`.

But why not pretend as if in mathematics by simply swapping the two options?
Like this:

```
find . \( -type d -name 'exclude_me' -prune \) -o \( -type f -a -print -a -iname '*.mp3' \)
```

Remember I set a precondition to have at least one non-mp3 file (e. g. image) in the . directory or its subdirectories. It has been set to give a clearer proof that this does *not* work as expected under the hood. Without them, things will merely *look* as working fine. *Having* them present instead will cause the non-mp3 files to get listed as well despite the distinct `-iname '*.mp3'` specification in the one-liner.
So why doesn't the `-a` operator work like in mathematics, where "A + B" is the same as "B + A"? Or, in `find` terms:

```
\( -type f -a -print -a -iname '*.mp3' \)
```

ought to be the same as

```
\( -type f -a -iname '*.mp3' -a -print \)
```

or not?

Is there no way to get the desired result *and* have the `-iname` argument at the end of the line, not anywhere in between?
(except for ugly hackish solutions like `grep -v exclude_me` or the like)

Comment: To boil richard's answer down to a sentence: `-a` is *never* commutative, but with `-print` you notice because `-print` has side-effects.

Comment: Do you have an answer to this?, I see that you have not accepted any of the answers. Do you need more help?

Answer (score 6):

`and` and `or` are not commutative in many programming languages e.g. C, C++, C♯, shells, find, and many more.

They use lazy left to right evaluated i.e. it evaluates the term on the left first, and then only evaluates term on right if it needs to. So in `false and b`, `b` is not evaluated as the answer is always false. But in `b and false`, `b` is evaluated, as it has not yet seen that the second term is false.

This does not make any difference when the terms are pure functions i.e. a predicate  (something that returns a boolean and does nothing else), but when it does something (has side effects) then it does matter.

`-print` does something. It prints, therefore it matters.

Note, Any system that allows side effects (such as -print), must define the order of evaluation, and left to right is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same. `-print` primary is always evaluated as true and causes the current pathname to be written to standard output.

When you use:

```
\( -type f -a -print -a -iname '*.mp3' \)
```

All files found will be printed to stdout, it's the [default behavior of -print](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_10), regardless of `-iname '*.mp3'` expression is true or false.

When you use:

```
\( -type f -a -iname '*.mp3' -a -print \)
```

`-print` part only reached if `-iname '*.mp3'` expression is true. So only files that end with `.mp3` will be printed.

POSIX define [find -a operator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05) as:

> expression  [-a]  expression
>
> Conjunction of primaries; the AND operator is implied by the
>   juxtaposition  of two primaries or made explicit by the optional -a
>   operator. **The second  expression shall not be evaluated if the first
>   expression is false.**

In this case, you don't have to use `-print`, because if the expression is true, `-print` is added by default:

> If no expression is present, -print shall be used as the expression.
>   Otherwise, if the given expression does not contain any of the
>   primaries -exec, -ok, or -print, the given expression shall be
>   effectively replaced by:
>
> ( given_expression ) -print

But this will cause **exclude_me** is printed in output, because when `find` matched it, `-prune` causes expression evaluated to true. And since when we had omitted `-print` in 2nd expresion, `-print` is added to the end of both expressions. It looks like:

```
find . \( -type d -name 'exclude_me' -prune \) -print -o \( -type f -a -iname '*.mp3' \) -print
```

This causes **exclude_me** is printed.

You can always omit **exclude_me** in output by explicitly adding a `-print` in 2nd expression. This causes `-print` only applied for 2nd expression:

```
find . \( -type d -name 'exclude_me' -prune \) -o \( -type f -a -iname '*.mp3' \) -print
```

Or adding an expression after `-prune`, and make sure that it makes the 1st expression false:

```
find . \( -type d -name 'exclude_me' -prune -a -name . \) -o \( -type f -a -iname '*.mp3' \)
```

Comment: Well, that's __not__ quite the same. Try it out. "./exclude_me" *does* get listed once you omit the `-print` at the end of the line. But I want it both excluded and not even listed at all. Not until you add the explicit `-print`, however, "exclude_me" will actually be left out of the listing. Trust me, I can try here "live" and I know what I'm talking about :)

Comment: Looks __excellent__ now in my opinion. Thanks for your agreement on improvement. As you have seen, this stuff is way trickier than it looks at first.-- Lastly, this has now turned a great solution for `alias` as well. Remember, `alias` needs the argument at the EOL, and the `-print` was in the way all the time. Thanks to your marvellous "dummy option" `-a -name .`, this is now feasible. Fantastic! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a shell function instead of an alias:

```
function my_find
{
   exclude_dir="$1"
   shift
   find . \( -type d -name "$exclude_dir" -prune \) -o \( -type f -a -iname "$@" -a -print \)
}
```