# How to find directories (or files, etc.) based on an expression that applies to the file pathname

Tags: find, regular-expression, directory, filenames

I'm trying to find/extract directories based on an expression
that applies to the file path. For example, I used the command:

```
find . -type d -links 2
```

To get a list of directories that looks something like this:

```
./foo/ABC/W
./foo/ABC/X
./foo/ABC/Y
./foo/ABC/Z
./foo/BCD/W
./foo/BCD/X
./foo/BCD/Y
./foo/BCD/Z
./foo/CDE/W
./foo/CDE/X
./foo/CDE/Y
./foo/CDE/Z
./bar/CDE/V
./bar/CDE/Q
./bar/BCD/V
./bar/BCD/Q
./bar/ABC/V
./bar/ABC/Q
```

I'm wondering how to take this list, and extract only filepaths containing say, "CDE" in them:

```
./foo/CDE/W
./foo/CDE/X
./foo/CDE/Y
./foo/CDE/Z
./bar/CDE/V
./bar/CDE/Q
```

This is what I've tried so far, which outputs nothing when I try it:

```
find . -type d -links 2 -name "CDE" -print
```

Comment: Yes, it's not working however. It outputs nothing when I try it.

Comment: I don't think that solution works for me since it doesn't print subdirectories. I need to have subdirectories printed out as well (which is why I used `-links 2`), I'm passing this to -exec to copy files into each subdirectory.

Comment: (1) `-print` is the *default* action, but I wouldn’t call it redundant.  Leaving it off will sometimes cause a command to fail; see  [`find` with multiple `-name` and `-exec` executes only the last matches of `-name`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191/80216), [Operator precedence in a find command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276574/80216), [find: Why is the `-a` operator not commutative in combination with `-print`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152941/80216), and others.  So don’t just forget that `-print` exists; you may need it sometimes.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (2) `-type d` will find all directories at all levels, including subdirectories. [As mentioned by Quasímodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/599613/80216#599665), *on a proper Unix system, using a standard Unixy filesystem,* `-type d -links 2` will find only directories ***that have no subdirectories**.* This does not work on Cygwin, and might not work on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), Ubuntu on Windows, Unix/Linux using a FAT disk or a file server like NetApp, etc.

Comment: See also [Find path that has specific sub directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/342392/80216) and [Further questions about -path for find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/200344/80216).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ find . -type d -links 2 -path '*CDE*'
./foo/CDE/X
./foo/CDE/Z
./foo/CDE/W
./foo/CDE/Y
./bar/CDE/Q
./bar/CDE/V
```

Or use

```
find . -type d -links 2 -path '*/CDE/*'
```

if you know `CDE` is the name of a subdirectory somewhere in the middle of the paths you're looking for.

Comment: Ah thanks! Knew it was something minor like that!

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -links 2 -name "CDE" -print
```

matches directories **whose basename** is exactly `CDE` (because of `-name CDE`) and that have no child directories (because of `-links 2`).

The basename of a file is just the bit after the last `/` of its path. For instance, the basename of `./foo/CDE/W` is `W`. From this you see that none of the directories matches both conditions.

You are after

```
find . -type d -links 2 -path '*/CDE/*'
```

[The `-path pattern` option is true if](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)

> the current pathname matches pattern using the pattern matching notation described in Pattern Matching Notation.

In the "Pattern Matching Notation", the asterisk matches any string.

As a last note, `-print` is used by default unless `-ok` or `-exec` are present, so you can drop it.